# Can we fill chines text(Not the unicode) into acrobat form and then flatten it using iTextPdf?

Tags: itextpdf

Can we fill chines text(Not the Unicode) into acrobat form and then flatten it? if yes can you please provide me the sample code? and steps ?

Comment: What have you tried? What does your form look like? Which font do the fields expect? You are not providing sufficient info for people wanting to answer this question.

Comment: Hi, I have created the form using adobe life cycle manager, the fields expecting SimHei font. now, I read this template using the iText and got the fields AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields(); then creating the font BaseFont bfComic = BaseFont.createFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/simhei.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED); then setting this font to feild,  form.setFieldProperty("field_Key", "textfont", bfComic, null); and then setting the value like form.setField((String) "field_Key", "黑体"); in this case if i doen't use the "stamper.setFormFlattening(true); text appearing on fields

Comment: But when i use the "stamper.setFormFlattening(true)" to flatten the pdf, then no text is appearing on the result pdf no text is appearing which i set above. i'm using itextpdf-5.1.0.jar and itext-asian.jar.

Comment: my objective is i have acrobat template which expecting the Chinese font "SimHei" then i need to fill this form and finally the form should be in the form of flattened. Please help me in this. and please give me the location where i can share the files

Comment: Forms created with Adobe LiveCycle are XFA forms. You are creating flattening techniques that are meant for flattening AcroForm fields. You really need to make your question more specific. For instance by sharing your form so that the basic question *"Are you filling an XFA form or an AcroForm?"* can be answered.

Comment: Thanks for your Replay, Please find the Form and java code in the below link "drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6WyeivpbZwcndnd21QSUdNV0U/…; and i want to use AcroForm only please suggest me proper tool for creating AcroForms and Share me the sample code to fill chines text into AcrForms, finally i need to flattening those forms.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I got your point, My clean question is here can we flatten the filled XFA(created with Adobe LiveCycle) or the Acrobat forms (created with acrobat s/w) using iTextAPI? please let me know the precess if possible? i tried with "stamper.setFormFlattening(true) but no results..